# Object and Parameter test

Tags: java, string, object, parameters

I have a simple question for a class I'm writing called AssassinNodeData. I'm trying to write a simple equals() method. I want to be able to check if the Object parameter is an AssassinNodeData object and this object’s player field is a case-insensitive match to the parameter’s player field.

This is little of what I have so far:

```
public boolean equals(Object data) {
    AssassinNodeData other = (AssassinNodeData) data; 
    if (!(data instanceof AssassinNodeData) && !other.getPlayer().equalsIgnoreCase(player)) 
        if (!( data instanceof String) && !other.getPlayer().equalsIgnoreCase(player))
            return false; 
    return true; 
}
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Well, your description talks about an `Object` parameter, but so far your method only has a `String` parameter...

Comment: @JonSkeet Aah I see - so should I change the parameter that I'm passing to Object instead of the String? I updated the code in the question's description.

Comment: Well you've updated the code so it's now of type `AssassinNodeData`, which still isn't what you described...

Comment: @JonSkeet Please elaborate, I'm not sure what your confusion is.

Comment: If you are passing AssassinNodeData data then why are you going to check is that a AssassinNodeData object?

Comment: "I want to be able to check if the Object parameter" - you still don't have an Object parameter, you have an AssassinNodeData parameter.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry - I see what you're saying now. Changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`equals` method shouldn't be `static`, the correct way of declaring it is:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
```

And here you need your code, example:

```
    if (!(obj instanceof AssassinNodeData)) {
        return false;
    }
    AssassinNodeData other = (AssassinNodeData) obj;
    return other.getPlayer.equals(player);
```

As you can see we first check if the object is a correct class, and later we cast it to the class that we expect it to be.
After that you just get fields from the other and compare them with current objects fields.

Comment: I updated the whole class and that is what came about - comments, suggestions?